# Kendo grid make detailinit expand and checkbox selected when select master table

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I create a similar [demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iziJikIP) relate with my situation. What I want to achieve when checked on the master grid, the details grid will expand and all the checkbox inside it will be checked and also the child grid is selected.

It's possible to do like this without using column template for the checkbox.
[DEMO IN DOJO](https://dojo.telerik.com/iziJikIP)

Example like this screen shot. (this one manually checked)
[image]

p/s: I found a [similar](http://dojo.telerik.com/@rkonstantinov/EGElI) demo, but this one using column.template for the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example code (which is based on your sample code) answers your requirement, which is...

> What I want to achieve when checked on the master grid, the details grid will expand and all the checkbox inside it will be checked and also the child grid is selected.

Try this in the Telerik DOJO. We need to wait for Kendo to finish expanding the detail row (making sure all HTML elements are fully built), hence the `setTimeout` in `detailExpand`. Change the delay depending on your needs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kendo Grid Master Detail Checkbox</title>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.3.1118/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  
<div id="example">
    <div id="grid"></div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Employees"
                    },
                    pageSize: 6,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true
                },
                height: 600,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                detailInit: detailInit,
                detailExpand: function(e) {
                    var $checkbox = $(e.masterRow.context);
                    if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            e.detailRow.find("tbody tr").each(function() {
                                var $row = $(this);
                                $row.find(".k-checkbox").each(function() {
                                    var $checkbox = $(this);
                                    $checkbox.attr("checked", true);
                                });
                                $(this).addClass("k-state-selected");
                            });                         
                        }, 250);
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    { selectable: true, width: 50 },
                    {
                        field: "FirstName",
                        title: "First Name",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "LastName",
                        title: "Last Name",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Country",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "City",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "Title"
                    }
                ]
            }).data("kendoGrid");
            
            grid.tbody.on("click", ".k-master-row .k-checkbox", function(e) {
                var $checkbox = $(this);

                if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
                    var $tr = $checkbox.closest("tr");
                    var $a = $tr.find(".k-hierarchy-cell a.k-icon");
                    
                    if ($a.length) {
                        if ($a.hasClass("k-i-expand")) {
                            grid.expandRow($tr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

        function detailInit(e) {
           var detailgrid = $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    transport: {
                        read: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"
                    },
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    filter: {
                        field: "EmployeeID",
                        operator: "eq",
                        value: e.data.EmployeeID
                    }
                },
                scrollable: false,
                sortable: true,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [
                    { selectable: true, width: 50, headerTemplate: ' '},
                    {
                        field: "OrderID",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "ShipCountry",
                        title: "Ship Country",
                        width: "110px"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "ShipAddress",
                        title: "Ship Address"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "ShipName",
                        title: "Ship Name",
                        width: "300px"
                    }
                ]
            }).data("kendoGrid");
          
        }
    </script>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The grid is expand when main checkbox is checked, but the sub record under it is not checked and selected.

Comment: Here are my new [updated.](https://dojo.telerik.com/iziJikIP/15). Question can we make sure the grid collapse first when loading and expand when we clicking on the main checkbox.

Comment: @dontbannedmeagain As explained, perhaps you need to increase the timeout a little bit. It's possible that the nested grid was not fully built, therefore the detail rows were not found.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted your first snippet based on the second one that you provided. Check out [this revised demo](https://dojo.telerik.com/iziJikIP/4).
Basically, you need to call `getKendoGrid()` and assign its return value (the actual grid) to the `grid` variable.
After that, add the `change` event listener as shown in the second demo snippet that you provided.

```js
grid.tbody.on("change", ".k-checkbox", function() {
  var checkbox = $(this);
  var nextRow = checkbox.closest("tr").next();
  // Note: the row should be expanded at least once as otherwhise there will be no child grid loaded                                        
  if (nextRow.hasClass("k-detail-row")) {
    // And toggle the checkboxes
    nextRow.find(":checkbox")
      .prop("checked", checkbox.is(":checked"));
  }
});
```

Also note that it's not `.master` as in the second demo, but `.k-checkbox`, as you are not providing a `template` in the first column (which the second demo does and the checkbox there has the `master` class).

Comment: Thanks for answering the question. But seem it still had an error on in. It need to double click first  in order to make child grid checkbox checked. And the child grid row is no selected.

Comment: @dontbannedmeagain, are you clicking the checkboxes? That works for me, the same way it does in your second example.

Comment: Seem the child grid need to be expand first, in order to make it happened.  Here are my new [updated.](https://dojo.telerik.com/iziJikIP/15). Question can we make sure the grid collapse first when loading and expand when we clicking on the parent checkbox.